# How to create a file with an non existing directory

Tags: python

```
current_directory = os.getcwd()
final_directory = os.path.join(current_directory, r'new_folder')
if not os.path.exists(final_directory):
   os.makedirs(final_directory)
   

async def handle(request):
    
    dir_list = os.listdir(final_directory)
    text = str(dir_list)
    return web.Response(text=text)
```

i use os.path.join to create a file in the directory that is created above, but it only creates the file with a directory like (r'C://blabla/bla/file.txt', 'w')

```
async def handler(requests):
    
    with open(os.path.join(final_directory, 'file.txt'), 'w') as fp:
        fp.write('This is first line')
    pass
```

Comment: It's not clear what you problem is without seeing all the code. Do you get an error if you don't enter a user defined path? Your usage of `os.path.join` seems fine; my best guess is `final_directory` must be invalid so I'd print that out somewhere to debug. The only potential issue I can see is you use [`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) to check whether you need to create a directory, however, this doesn't cater for the case you were there is a file with a name `new_folder`. This should throw an error when you call `os.listdir` though.

Comment: i tried that but it doesnt create de file

Comment: i need to create a file, when post method is requested. so i created a folder in the current path to use that path to create the file. So i dont have any problem on creating the file on another computer

Comment: but it only creates the file and doesnt create de file

Comment: It's difficult to advise without knowing anything more about your code. A stack trace from when the error occurs would really help; logging `final_directory` at the point of failure would also help. It looks like it could be running a web server on Windows?  You could be running into permissions issues on a server environment you're not expecting. If so, you could run [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon?source=recommendations); this should be able to tell you if a file operation is failing and why.